# Cassette Add Individual Javascript Script Link Reference Inline

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to add an inline script link reference using Cassette?

What I want is to be able to add something like the following to my page:

`@Bundles.AddInlineScriptReference("/MyScripts/TheScript.js")`

*(note: Bundles.AddInlineScriptReference doesn't exists, just an example)*

and have Cassette write out the script link including handling the minification, etc.

`<script src="/cassette.axd/asset/MyScripts/TheScript.js?voB4kL0uy2HIpjkJnSuycghlp-8=" type="text/javascript"></script>`

I see a way to add inline scripts and bundles but not script link references. I could setup bundles that include individual files. However that seems like it's unnecessarily tedious for a single script that's used throughout an entire section of a site.

Reading the Cassette Bundle helper documentation I thought something like this would work.

`@Bundles.Reference("/MyScripts/TheScript.js")`

However it throws the following error:

`Cannot find an asset bundle containing the path`

I'd appreciate any advice. I feel like this is such a simple question that I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
 bundles.Add<ScriptBundle>("MyBundle", new[]{ "path/to/script/script.js"});
```